# How to get around hard coding a PFX password

Tags: tls, authentication, code-review

I've got an application that acts as a SSL server. I've got the pfx file and in code, I've had to hard code the password to use in the following way

```
PKCS12_parse(p12, PFXPassword, &pkey, &cert, &ca)
```

The more that I read on here, the more that I'm realizing how susceptible my code would be to reverse-engineering and thus extracting the password out of the code itself. How would I go about protecting myself from this?

I expect my code to be eventually (hopefully) be deployed in boxes that I have no control of, so just keeping it to myself doesn't seem like a plausible idea.

Comment: Have you looked at the usual put it in a file, and each box gets a different password?

Comment: would that require each box to get a new cert with a new password? I was hoping to use a single cert for this.

Comment: There is no way you can allow the server to have access to the key, while preventing anyone who has full access to the server from having access to the key.

Comment: Sadly @immibis is right. Once the box is in physical ownership of someone else they can do whatever they want to it and grab that password/cert out. This means there are many different approaches to trying to keep yourself and your customers secure. You're going to have to explore a bit to narrow down what you want to do to a few key options that should keep the headache low enough.

Comment: Thank you all for your input! I was worried that there might not be an easy out to my problem and am thinking about re-engineering the whole shebang to avoid having to deploy the certs/keys out into the wild. Thanks again!

Comment: Using /dev/random would generate a unique password, or having a master server that each unit phones home.  Using a password from a site that generates passwords like grc.com, every time the server starts up goto https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm  and get a new password. It would be super easy to scrap the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask me having to update code when you change certificates is a pretty poor design, but that wasn't your question.

The only way to protect the private key from the server itself is to offload SSL operations to a trusted host. If you're concerned about the private key's safety on the server, you could get a hardware security module (HSM) which securely stores the private key and performs the necessary crypto operations in a secure isolated environment.

Honestly though, if you're not going to use an HSM you may as well store the key in plaintext rather than hardcode a password into your application because that's only the illusion of protection. Without an HSM, one way or another the server has to have the private key to operate and someone with control of the server can just rip it right out of memory if they want.